# iframe auto height to 100%

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get this iframe to auto-adjust its height but whatever I do, it won't work! I have tried various combinations of using positions and other tricks in css. Somehow I'm missing out on something crucial.

I can't use min-height or max-height since the forms will be different everytime and a lot of whitespace will be created.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <iframe style="height: 100%;width: 100%; margin: 0;" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1406PEfzY-ZV_nx2mACr6DBoyxm95JfGvhWftOml73xg/viewform?embedded=true" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could someone suggest where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Add `position:absolute` and make padding and margin as 0 for the body in your style. If you set it to absolute, it will position relative to its first positioned ancestor element

[Working JS](https://jsfiddle.net/hmv8c5bd/1/)

Hope it works in your case :)

Comment: No, your code is not working even in the demo. I see 2 scrollers.

Comment: it works for me. Yes, u are right. U should set padding and margin to 0 for body

Comment: for some reason, i can't get this to work with bootstrap :(